# Mongo/Morphia querying for entire document

Tags: java, json, mongodb, orm, morphia

I run the following Mongo client command:

```
db.Role.insert(
    {
        name: "Common",
        alias: "COMMON",
        description: "Common role"
    }
);
```

This succeeds. Then inside my JVM app (that uses [Mongo/Morphia 1.0.1](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/releases)) I run the following command:

```
System.out.println(datastore.find(Role.class)
    .field("alias").equal("COMMON").toString())
```

Which prints the following to the console:

```
{"alias": "COMMON"}
```

So it seems that my query is only querying my `Role` collection for a *field* with a key of "`alias`" and a value of "`COMMON`". **But I don't want this!** I want a query that will return the **entire** "*Common*" `Role` document (as a JSON string, not mapped to a POJO). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphia's behavior is to return the full object. You need to explicitly [ignore fields](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#ignoring-fields) if you don't want to include them in your result.

<s>Does your `.toString()` include all attributes?</s>

Are you sure you're actually loading this document? Maybe there's another one with `alias: "COMMON"` as well?

You're missing the `.get()` (or `.asList()` if there were multiple ones):

```
System.out.println(datastore.find(Role.class)
    .field("alias").equal("COMMON").get().toString())
```

Comment: Thanks @xeraa (+1): **(1)** I'm confused when you ask me if *my* `.toString()` includes all attributes...because I never overrode `Role#toString()` and so I figured Morphia was producing that `{"alias": "COMMON"}` JSON string for me...**it's certainly not anything I wrote!** Also **(2)** From the Mongo shell, running `db.Role.find({ alias: "COMMON" }).count();` produces the value "`1`", so **yes**, I am sure its loading the right document.

Comment: And **(3)** I have `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` and `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotated on my `Role` entity (as well as `@Entity`)...did I go awry there by any chance?

Comment: Ahh, you're missing the `.get()`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @xeraa (+1 again) but that goes ahead and does the actual mapping for me (from JSON back into a POJO). The reason why I'm interested in seeing the actual JSON that is coming back from Mongo is because when I add `.get()` at the end of that query, I get a weird `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: <large string here>` exception, telling me that something is wrong with my mapping. But I can't tell if the JSON (which I added manually) is bad, or if my mapping annotations are bad. Thoughts?

Comment: If you're using Morphia, there's no JSON. Looks like you have a string in your database where your POJO expects a number. Can you add your entity to the question?